# Are there Any free XSL-FO editors?

Tags: editor, xsl-fo

I am looking for a free WYSIWYG editor of XSL-FO.

Specifically, I would like to be able to design the FO file through a visual editor.

I am aware of some that are available for purchase and evaluation, however I was wondering if there are any free editors available?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ can at least help you keep track of your tags.  Just load your XSL-FO code in, change your language to XML, and you'll get color-coded text with expandable tag-matching.

Sorry I couldn't offer anything more robust, but that'll at least save you a little heartache.

I could also recommend the lite version of EditiX, though it's not WYSIWIG, and I'm only just starting to use it myself, so take this with a grain of salt, and at your own discretion.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was using Notepad++ at the time. Will reconsider using XSL-FO in future projects due to complexity.  Reporting Services is usually a much simpler alternative.